# How to get city under country in auto complete search using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

This is html my code

```
<input type="text" name="country" id="country"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#country').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "get_country.php",
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {

        }
    });
});

var country = $("#country").val(); 

$('#city').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "get_city.php",
        //type:"GET",
        data : 'country='+country,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {

        }
    });
});

});
```

This is my code get_city.php

```
include_once('config.php');

if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
exit;

$country = $_POST['country'];

$rs = mysql_query('select city from xyz_table where country="$country" and city like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by city asc limit 0,10');

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
    $data[] = array(
        'value' => $row['city']
    );
}
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

here is showed below problem **Notice**: Undefined index: country in **G:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\get_city.php** on line **6**

I have get country in  auto complete search  such as Germany , United Kingdom

I want to get auto complete search city under country (for example Germany/United Kingdom)

How can i solve it , Please any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$rs = mysql_query('select city from xyz_table where country="$country" and city like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by city asc limit 0,10');
```

to

```
$rs = mysql_query("select city from xyz_table where country='$country' and city like '". mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) ."%' order by city asc limit 0,10");
```

See the difference In your query `$country` was set as string not the actual `country`.

use this

```
$_REQUEST['country']
```

send the data using this

```
data : { country : country },
```

Declare `country` inside call

```
$('#city').keydown(function(){
    var country = $("#country").val();
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "get_city.php",
        ............
```

Comment: here is showed below problem Notice: Undefined index: country in G:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\get_city.php on line 6 then same problem using $_REQUEST['country']  Yogesh Suthar

Comment: I am really disappointed , i don't know why don't become it? Yogesh Suthar

Comment: @MD.ABDULHalim Debug with `firebug` and check weather it is calling `get_city.php` and passing which value. and see the result.

Comment: I have debug with firebug but i think that country value don't pass .  Yogesh Suthar